# How to config datasource in WSO2 Stream Integrator 7.1.0 to auto reconnect mysql

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-streaming-integrator

I've tried to setup a datasource connect to MySQL in deployment.yaml of WSO2 SI so that I can use it in my Siddhi apps.
It worked fine as normal but when I restart MySQL, the datasource can not reconnect to DB so my Siddhi app get following errors.

How can I config datasource so it can auto reconnect after database restart.

Thank you,
Luong.

```
[2020-11-12 19:32:43,627] ERROR {io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.polling.strategies.DefaultPollingStrategy} - Error occurred while processing records in table SweetProductionTable. {mode=polling, app=CDCWithPollingMode, stream=insertSweetProductionStream} java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:493)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:315)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.polling.strategies.DefaultPollingStrategy.printEvent(DefaultPollingStrategy.java:142)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.polling.strategies.DefaultPollingStrategy.poll(DefaultPollingStrategy.java:86)
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.polling.CDCPoller.run(CDCPoller.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of siddhi-io-cdc.
A Siddhi app with CDC polling mode get errors when the source database restart.
These failures caused by the bug in DefaultPollingStrategy class, printEvent(connection) do not verify connection before using it, must getConnection() first.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the mysql connection URL can you add the following

```
&amp;autoReconnect=true
```

For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_api_stat_alt?useSSL=false&ampautoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Thank you Shanaka, I've tried as you suggested, but it could not reconnect.

Comment: You can reproduce this errors by following these steps:
1. Config datasource to MySQL
2. Use datasource in CDC @Souce in Siddhi app
3. Restart MySQL
--> Errors caused by DB connection is closed.
I found that WSO2SI use Hikari Connection Pool but it can not reconnect to DB after connection lost.
Do you know how to config Hiraki CP so that it can auto reconnect all lost connection in pool ?